# Cannot create COM object

Tags: asp-classic, iis-express

I'm debugging an application written in classic ASP.  I'm using IIS Express 7.5 to be able to debug the application.  All is fine, until I reach the following line:

```
set somevariable =Server.CreateObject("somelibrary.somemember")
```

"Unknown exception" is raised.

**Context**

I have administrative rights.
The OS is Windows XP SP3.
The "somelibrary" assembly was correctly registered with regasm and included in the GAC with gacutil.
I'm be able to execute the assembly from PowerShell:

```
$instance =New-Object -ComObject "somelibrary.somemember")
```

I have the following configuration in IIS Express for ASP:

```
 <asp enableParentPaths="true"
  bufferingOn="true"
  errorsToNTLog="true"
  appAllowDebugging="true"
  appAllowClientDebug="true"
  scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true">
      <session allowSessionState="true" />
      <cache diskTemplateCacheDirectory="%TEMP%\iisexpress\ASP Compiled Templates" />
      <limits />
 </asp>
```

The site has windows and anonymous authentication enabled (disabling windows authentication gets the same)

What could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: XP is not exactly the best OS to do anything IIS-related.  Did you check event log?  Try running procmon and see if IIS even tries to access the DLL in question.  If it is not, some IIS setting probably needs to be tweaked...

Comment: What is the HRESULT value returned from the error? You can get this value from Err.Number when you trap the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a computer restart all is working fine.  Looking in the event log I see entries indicating that there is no information about errors occurred in ASP and suggesting to use the /AUXSOURCE flag to get more details.  I guess IIS Express lacks this help messages.